# Why auto suggestions are not showing in eclipse maven web project

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I Created Maven Web project in the eclipse.Everything is fine but when I pressed the <kbd>ctrl+space</kbd> for the auto suggestions but it nothing shows relevant to my class dependencies.am I did any thing wrong please someone suggest me..It spoils my entire day...

Comment: Did you check some of the possible fixes here http://www.mkyong.com/java/content-assist-ctrl-space-is-not-working-eclipse/?

Comment: does eclipse have the src folder correctly configured?